# Accept 2 Strings and display common chars in them

Tags: java, string

I am using the code below to find common characters in two strings. Sometimes this code produces wrong results such as giving output value which is greater than string lengths.

```
for(int i = 0;i < num1.length();i++){
                for(int j =0;j < num2.length();j++){
                    if(num1.charAt(i) == num2.charAt(j)){
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: use num1.charAt(i).equals(num2.charAt(j)) instead of == for string comparison

Comment: @albertoqa He's comparing characters? I don't think you need `.equals`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Count can go beyond the length of the string in the case some characters get duplicated in either string. You might want to keep adding the duplicated characters to a set

Comment: No, the use of "equals" is not necessary. "charAt" returns a "char" value that can safely be compared using ==.

Comment: Please give a example of your expected input/output

Comment: because of inner loop, you are getting greater results. And
Count can go beyond the length of the string in the case some characters get duplicated in either string

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Your code can produce results greater than the string length because of characters that appear more than once in your strings. You can get results of up to num1.length() * num2.length().

In case you want to get the number of positions at which you have the same character in both strings, you can to that in just one loop and use the same index for the "charAt" calls on both strings:

```
for(int i = 0; i < num1.length() && i < num2.length(); i++) {
    if(num1.charAt(i) == num2.charAt(i)){
        count++;
    }
}
```

In case you want to get the number of unique letters that appear in both strings, run through both strings independently and add the letters to a set. Then intersect both sets. The number of elements in that intersection set is your result:

```
    Set<Character> characters1 = new TreeSet<Character>();
    for(int i = 0; i < num1.length(); i++) {
        characters1.add(num1.charAt(i));
    }

    Set<Character> characters2 = new TreeSet<Character>();
    for(int i = 0; i < num2.length(); i++) {
        characters2.add(num2.charAt(i));
    }

    characters1.retainAll(characters2);
    return characters1.size();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this using [**HashSet**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class QuickTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s1 = "happy";
        String s2 = "elephant";

        Set<Character> set1 = new HashSet<Character>();
        Set<Character> set2 = new HashSet<Character>();

        for(char c : s1.toCharArray()) {
            set1.add(c);
        }
        for(char c : s2.toCharArray()) {
            set2.add(c);
        }

        // Stores the intersection of set1 and set2 inside set1
        set1.retainAll(set2);

        for(char c : set1) {
            System.out.print(" " + c);
        }

        System.out.println("\nTotal number of common characters: "
            + set1.size());
    }
}
```

Refer to [retainAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)) on how the intersection of 2 sets is done.

**Input Strings:**

```
happy
elephant
```

**Output:**

```
 p a h
Total number of common characters: 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils to count matches like this

```
    String num1 = "Java";
    String num2 = "Guava";
    int count = 0;
    List<String> charsChecked = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0;i < num1.length();i++){
        String charToCheck = num1.substring(i, i+1);

        if (!charsChecked.contains(charToCheck)) {
            count += StringUtils.countMatches(num2, charToCheck);
            charsChecked.add(charToCheck);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(count);
```

This results in the count being 3 in the above example