# Find the intersection of two strings in which characters appearing in both strings are returned (same sequence order as 1st String)

Tags: java, string, hashmap, hashset

I am using HashMap() for the problem but am facing issues with regards to order and occurrence of characters in output.

I tried to reverse the String builder both while iteration and after StringBuilder was created, still face another issues.

```
int l1 = inputStr1.length();
int l2 = inputStr2.length();

StringBuilder mkr = new StringBuilder();

HashMap<Character, Integer> res  = new HashMap<>();

for (int i = 0; i < l1; i++) {
           res.put(inputStr1.charAt(i),i);
        } 

    for (int j = 0; j < l2; j++) {
        if (res.containsKey(inputStr2.charAt(j))){
            mkr.append(inputStr2.charAt(j));

        }
}

mkr = mkr.reverse(); // Code only used in Test Scenario - 2
String result = mkr.toString();

if(result == null){return null;}

return result;
```

Test Scenario 1 -
Input String 1 : Hello
Input String 2 : world
Expected output is:  lo 
Actual output generated by my code: ol

Test Scenario 2 - [After reversing the StringBuilder]
Input String 1: hi you are good
Input String 2 : hi man
Expected output is:  hi a 
Actual output generated by my code: a ih

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30662384/accept-2-strings-and-display-common-chars-in-them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, found the solution with help of @askipop :

```
 if(inputStr1 == null || inputStr2 == null){
            return null;
        }

        String res = "";

        HashMap<Character, Integer> hm = new HashMap<>(); 

        for(int i = 0; i < inputStr2.length(); i++){
            Character c = inputStr2.charAt(i);
            if(hm.containsKey(c)){
                hm.put(c, hm.get(c) + 1);
            } else{
                hm.put(c, 1);
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < inputStr1.length(); i++){
            Character ch = inputStr1.charAt(i);
            if(hm.containsKey(ch)){
                res += ch;
                int c = hm.get(ch);
                if (c - 1 > 0){
                    hm.put(ch, c - 1);
                } else{
                    hm.remove(ch);
                }
            }
        }

        if(res.length() > 0){
            return res;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems to be correct.  But since you are expecting the final intersection characters to be in order with input String 1, instead of creating a hashmap of characters for string 1, and iterating over string 2, if those operations are reversed, it would give you the expected answer.  But this may return duplicates.  For e.g, if inputString1 = 'apple' and inputString2 = 'pot', this method may return two p's instead of 1.  To avoid this problem, you can remove the character from hashmap once it matches with character in inputString1.

```
int l1 = inputStr1.length();
int l2 = inputStr2.length();

StringBuilder mkr = new StringBuilder();

HashMap<Character, Integer> res  = new HashMap<>();

for (int i = 0; i < l2; i++) {
       res.put(inputStr2.charAt(i),i);
} 

for (int j = 0; j < l1; j++) {
    if (res.containsKey(inputStr1.charAt(j))){
        res.remove(inputStr1.charAt(j));
        mkr.append(inputStr1.charAt(j);

    }
}

String result = mkr.toString();
if(result == null){return null;}
return result;
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
As per the testcases provided, repitition is fine. 

The Output should only contain - > No. of Character occurrences present on String 2 in the order of String1.

Example Test Case :
I tried running the code by creating a HashMap on String2 and iterated over String1 but found the below issue.

Input string1 : Hello
Input String 2 : world
Expected output is:  lo 
Actual output generated by my new code: llo

Comment: Thank you for the valuable comment.

As per the problem statement, repetition is fine. 

The Output should only contain - > No. of Character occurrences present on String 2 in the order of String1.

Example Test Case with remove() enabled on HashMap :

Input 1: mmm
Input 2 : mmm
Expected output is:  mmm 
Actual output: m

Found below result, after running code by creating a HashMap on String2 and iterated over String1 without remove():

Input String1 : Hello
Input String 2 : world
Expected output is:  lo 
Actual output: llo

Could you please advise on this issue?

Comment: What answer do you expect for string1: lol and string2: lllollll. Is it lllollll or lllllllo?